# How to enable save as popup window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

I'm new to html. I just wanna know how to get the save as pop up in my html page. I have tried the html input file type attribute. But it doesn't work for me. I need to show the download pop up to the user not the upload pop up. 
Following image shows what i actually need,
[image]

Can someone please give me an idea how to get this done. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you set the mime header `application/octet-stream` on the server on the request, the browser will pop the download too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) element with `download` attribute set, call `click()` on the element.

```html
<a href="" download=""></a>
<script>
  document.querySelector("a[download]").click()
</script>
```

alternatively, you can set `href` at `a` element to `data URI` having MIME type `application/octet-stream`, call `.click()` on element

```html
<a href="data:application/octet-stream," id="download"></a>
<script>
  document.querySelector("a#download").click()
</script>
```

Comment: i tried this but nothing happens. i need to get the popup window to download

Comment: Your second example might pop the download, but for what? Nothing to save. The application/octet-stream needs to be set on the server,

Comment: @Dayan _"i tried this but nothing happens. i need to get the popup window to download"_ What are you trying to achieve? What do you mean by "get pop window to download"? Download what? User needs to click `"Save"` or `"Save as"` button

Comment: @mplungjan `application/octet-stream` can be text to download as file. Try adding "abc" following comma `,` at stacksnippets. OP did not ask to download file, but how to generate "Save As" dialog. Did not include text to download at stacknsippets

Comment: I have a button. when user clicks it, i need to show the download pop up, in where user will be able to choose a downloading path. i need to pass that path to the server. i just need to get the downloading path from the user.

Comment: The path selected by user to download file at user filesystem is not available as a return value from `Save as` dialog. Why do you want the path to a downloaded file at user filesystem?

Comment: then how do i know where to download the file. i need to get the path from the user, for example @"C:\sample.xlsx

Comment: _"then how do i know where to download the file."_ ? The user can download the file to any permissible folder at the user filesystem. User can also change name of file. Or move file to a different location after download. What is purpose of retrieving path to file at users' filesystem? Not certain what you are trying to achieve?